# Distribution sort in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, distribution

I am wondering if there is any method in C# support distribution sort: like counting sort or bucket sort.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Built in to the framework? No. Plenty of implementations abound on Google though, I'm sure. Or, you can roll your own.